# C# declare empty string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need to declare an empty string array and i'm using this code

```
string[] arr = new String[0]();
```

But I get "method name expected" error.

What's wrong?

Comment: also tried with string[] error = new String[0]{}();

Comment: Why do you need an empty array? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MrT. not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @James - maybe there is a more elegant way to do whatever he is trying to do.

Comment: i need empty array because i need to return it from a function (when i catch error)

Comment: @aquanat - although an answer has already been accepted and i don't know your code or the logic behind it, i would humbly suggest you not to return an empty array but null and check from the calling function if the returned value is null or not. I think that it would be much more elegant, readable and efficient.

Comment: i use this empty array because my function use webclient to get a list of email from webpage. but if there's 404err or some others like this, due to not manage all error and exception i used to return this kind of array...hope it's clear :-) (and sorry for my delay for my answer

Comment: ..after i used null array, it's the same, but more elegant :-)

Comment: The reason you would not want to return null is that the consumer of the method has to check for null. For instance, the consumer of the method could put the returned value in a foreach and if an empty array is returned, there is no problem. However, if null is returned, there has to be a check for null before iterating the returned value

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Try this

```
string[] arr = new string[] {};
```

Comment: Thanks everybody...don't ask me why, but the only way was:

    string[] arr = new String[0] as string[];

Comment: Atish's method worked and eliminated visual studio's complain about using a variable that is not initialized if I assign it in an if statement

Comment: Other option is ```c# Array.Empty<string>()```

Comment: **This method** is not the current best practice and **should not be the accepted answer** as it allocates unneeded memory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1825). Use the syntax that @Brian mention to prevent this.

Answer (score 78):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
string[] arr = new string[]{};
```

or

```
string[] arr = new string[0];
```

Comment: Why is string both capitalized and not capitalized in you examples?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance, just copied code "as is" from the question. Both lines compile fine, although I agree that following one style is better.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using  **.NET Framework 4.6 and later**, they have some new syntax you can use:

```
using System;  // To pick up definition of the Array class.

var myArray = Array.Empty<string>();
```

Comment: Nice trick! And it also works with IList<T> : IList<string> x = Array.Empty<string>();

Answer (score 9):

You can try this

```
string[] arr = {};
```

Comment: This is, surprisingly, resulting in `null` for me when using within an object initializer.

Answer (score 8):

Arrays' constructors are different. Here are some ways to make an empty string array:

```
var arr = new string[0];
var arr = new string[]{};
var arr = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray()
```

(sorry, on mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is invalid.

```
string[] arr = new string[5];
```

That will create `arr`, a referenced array of strings, where all elements of this array are `null`. (Since strings are *reference types*)

This array contains the elements from `arr[0]` to `arr[4]`. The `new` operator is used to create the array and initialize the array elements to their default values. In this example, all the array elements are initialized to `null`.

[`Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0a7fscd0.aspx)

Comment: Thanks everybody...don't ask me why, but the only way was:

    string[] arr = new String[0] as string[];

Answer (score 0):

If you must create an empty array you can do this:

```
string[] arr = new string[0];
```

If you don't know about the size then You may also use `List<string>` as well like

```
var valStrings = new List<string>();

// do stuff...

string[] arrStrings = valStrings.ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I accidentally ruined your post with wrong edits.

Answer (score 0):

Those curly things are sometimes hard to remember, that's why there's excellent [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx):

```
// Declare a single-dimensional array  
int[] array1 = new int[5];
```

Comment: No need to edit this answer, as answers serve the gereral purpose, and not the specific question per say. It answers _"What is the syntax to declare and initialize an array"_ and is a citation from the link I posted. OP can replace `int` with `string` if he likes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// zero-element array
var arr0 = System.Array.Empty<string>(); // Recommended: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1825
var arr1 = new string[0];

// 5-Elements array with null values
var arr2 = new string[5];

// 5-Elements array with empty string values
var arr3 = System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 5).ToArray();
var arr4 = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(_ => string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

could get something like this with:
private List list = new List();
string[] dnormlines kist.ToArray();

Answer (score -5):

The following should work fine.

```
string[] arr = new string[] {""};
```

Comment: That's not an empty array, as it contains one element which is an empty string. arr.Length() will return 1.

Comment: This may not be an empty array but I find this answer null safe. Thanks! 1 up!